# Remove SalesRule from Quote Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, event-observer, sales-quote

I want to remove the SalesRule from Quote if rule Coupon type is

> Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON

I have this code:

```
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote = $event->getQuote();
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $appliedRule = $event->getRule();

    if (strlen($quote->getCouponCode()) > 0) {
        $quote->setCouponCode('');
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }

    return $this;
```

which works fine if I want to remove the Coupon code which I set in the salesRule. But same rule does not work for Coupon type which I have mentioned above.

I have tried solutions like iterating through quote Items and setting the **appliedRules** to null and **discount amount, value** to zero but nothing worked. E.g.

```
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote = $event->getQuote();
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $appliedRule = $event->getRule();

    $giftcards = $quote->getGiftCards();
    $giftCardsData = unserialize($giftcards);

    if ($appliedRule->getCouponType() == Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON) {
                foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    $item->setAppliedRuleIds('');
                    $item->setDiscountPercent(0);
                    $item->setDiscountAmount(0);
                    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(0);
                    $item->save();
                }
            }
```

Or also tried setting AppliedRules to null in QUOTE and ADDRESS:

```
if ($appliedRule->getCouponType() == Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON) {
            $address->setAppliedRuleIds('');
            $quote->setAppliedRuleIds('');
        }
```

But no success so far. I will be great full if someone can tell me how can I remove the SalesRule from the Quote.

By the way above code is running under

> salesrule_validator_process

Event.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself although I am not sure how efficient this answer is.
As previously mentioned the code is executing in the

> salesrule_validator_process

this event pass following data with itself:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_validator_process', array(
                'rule'    => $rule,
                'item'    => $item,
                'address' => $address,
                'quote'   => $quote,
                'qty'     => $qty,
                'result'  => $result,
            ));
```

You can find the code in class **app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php** under function 
**public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)** 
of Magento EE

The **RESULT** contains the information of **DISCOUNT AMOUNT** and **BASE DISCOUNT AMOUNT**

I simply changed the value of these two to zero which helps me resolving my problem. Below is the complete code:

```
public function YourFunctionName($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote = $event->getQuote();
    $appliedRule = $event->getRule();
    $result = $event->getResult();

    $giftcards = $quote->getGiftCards();
    $giftCardsData = unserialize($giftcards);

    if (!empty($giftCardsData)) {
        if (!$appliedRule->getIsUsableWithGiftCard()) {
            if ($appliedRule->getCouponType() == Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON) {
                $result->setDiscountAmount(0); /// Here it is
                $result->setBaseDiscountAmount(0);  /// Here it is
            } else {
                $quote->setCouponCode('');
                $quote->collectTotals()->save();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```